# Additive Color Composition in Matplotlib: Combine Red and Green to Get Yellow

Tags: matplotlib, colors

Here is a plot where semi-transparent red and yellow dots are shown.

I was counting on obtaining a yellowish hue, when green and red dots are superposed, but this is obviously not what is happening (see figure).

Am I wrong that red and green colors should combine additively?

Can somebody explain how to use an additive color combination model to achieve my goal?

[image: yellow and red dots]

Comment: Colors are combined "subtractively", meaning red and green will overlay to brownish.

Comment: Colors are combined subtractive but light combines additively. Can we change the model how matplotlib behaves?

Comment: Not easily. Some starting point is [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6210).